# Bifurcation diagram for Chau's Circuit

Tags: python

I need to draw a bifurcation diagram for the Chau's circuit but I am not too sure how to do this. What I've done so far, I've ploted x(t) versus t to get max and min of my x(t) and plot them against bifurcation parameter m0, however I doesn't give me the bifurcation diagram. I appreciate if you can help me with this. Thank you

Comment: Please provide the code you have so far

Comment: Hi I am not too sure why I can't put my code here

Comment: It tells me it is not in the right format, while I can run it in my jupyter

Comment: Copy the code as text and paste it as code block. (``` before and after the code)

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example